# C++ alternative of rust's proc macros

Tags: c++, rust, macros

Rust have very amazing feature to generate code at compile using proc_macros which are pure rust code. is there is anything similar in C++ which lets me executes real C++ code to generate code instead of ugly defines.

Comment: Yes. Templates are instanced at compile-time. `constexpr`s may be evaluated at compile-time. Furthermore, the compiler tries to evaluate at compile-time what's possible e.g. using const propagation. (I'm knowing too less about Rust to tell how comparable this is to Rust's proc macros.)

Comment: The closest thing I can think of to "C++ code that generates C++ code" (as part of the language) would be the [metaclasses proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0707r4.pdf) but thats a ways off and not really comparable to Rust's procedural macros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing built into C++ to achieve the equivalent of Rust proc-macros, at the moment.

Traditionally, in C++, I have seen 2 different ways to achieve a similar effect:

- Code generation: a separate executable runs as part of the build to generate C++ files. For example LLVM features [TableGen](https://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/).
- Preprocessing: a separate executable preprocesses C++ files and transforms them prior to the build process. For example QT features [MOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-object_System).

I would argue that QT's MOC is closer in spirit to Rust proc-macros, and LLVM TableGen is closer to Rust's `build.rs`.

---

Herb Sutter has been proposing [meta-classes](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/), which would cover a subset of the proc-macros: the derive macros.

It would not cover the use of proc-macros to transform the code of functions, or otherwise generate arbitrary code in-situ.